# How to generate a bundle of patches from TortoiseHG 2.0.5, Changeset Ranges

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Hi I am trying to use the version 2.0.5., how do me make a bundle of all the changes from a certain revision to tip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to 2.1 has solved the problem.

Comment: it's TortoiseHg 3.4.1 now. Workbench can only bundle 2 changeset maximum with the right click and export sub menu. To bundle more than 2 changesets you must use hg command line "hg bundle -r upperRevNumber --base lowerRevNumber yourOutputfilename.hg "

Comment: Ignore my above comment :) apparently with workbench,you can select ranges but must ctrl+click upper changeset and lower changeset, then generate bundle. silly me

Answer (score 4):

In TortoiseHg 2.1 Workbench:

1. Right-click on the revision.
2. Go to the **Export** submenu.
3. Click on **Bundle rev to tip...**
4. Choose where to save the bundle.

Comment: There is no Bundle rev to tip! All I have in the export submenu are : expprt patch, email patch, Archive,copy patch... I don`t he export bundle...

Answer (score 2):

You could use `hg bundle` for the task:

```
hg bundle -r tip --base REV v2.0.5
```

The above will create a bundle with changesets from `REV` to `tip`.

Comment: Ho can I do that in the workbench?  In the previous version we used to have Bundle...Now it`s no more there?

Comment: Does "workbench" refer to the new tortoiseHg interface? If so you can use the Archive command from the right-click menu to produce a bundle.

Comment: it`s in mercurial version 2.0.5

Comment: You probably mean it's in TortoiseHg 2.0.5, which contains Mercurial (which itself is still at v1.9). There's an important distinction between the two.